# Possibility of Saving Hidden Value in a Repeat Group as A Case Property in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

Is it possible to save a hidden value as a case property, especially if the hidden value is a repeated value? I have attached a screenshot of what the derivation of the field that I want to save as a case value (full_name) looks like.

[[image: Branching for full_name Variable][1]]

Answer (score 1):

Since repeat groups produce multiple values there is no way to know how they should be combined or selected to produce the case property value.

The way to do this is to create a hidden value outside of the repeat group which produces the final value that you want to save to the case. This could use a function like [concat](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Functions#CommCareFunctions-concat) to join all the repeat group values together.

You can find more information on the [Advanced Functions for Repeat Groups](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Advanced+Functions+for+Repeat+Groups) page in the docs.